# How to centre fluid image and a caption using CSS Flexbox?

Tags: html, css, image, flexbox

Please consider a layout where an image and a caption, both of variable dimensions, should be centred on the screen.

[image]

Layout should behave like this (consult the figure above):

1. If an image and a caption are small enough to fit the screen, then nothing special happen and they just get centred.
2. If an image and a caption doesn’t fit screen height, an image gets shrunk until they do.
3. If an image doesn’t fit screen width, it gets shrunk until it does.

How to achieve this mechanics using CSS Flexbox?

**Update.**  If the caption doesn't fit the screen, image should shrink until it does.

[image]

Comment: What's the context for this? Where is the code? Flexbox is not needed for such a requirement.

Comment: @ralph.m no code. This should be done with no javascript and be fast. Modern browsers only is okay. Flexbox is not a strict requirement, but looks like a good option.

Comment: Flexbox isn't supported by Safari which means you may have to develop a non-flexbox solution anyway.

Comment: @adamdc78 - [Safari certainly does support Flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox). It just requires the `-webkit` prefix currently.

Comment: Ahhh, on 7.1+, good to know!

Comment: Why has this not been closed? This is a "do this work for me" question... No code shown, no effort shown in attempts by the OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I really had to pay more attention maintaining this question.

It seems that the problem could not be solved without Javascript. I've started with an idea proposed by @Danield, applied some Javascript and came up with the following solution.

```js
$figure = $('figure');
$figcaption = $('figcaption');
$img = $('img');

$(window).resize(function() {
  var height = $figure.height() - $figcaption.height();
  $img.css('max-height', Math.max(height, 0));
}).resize();
```

```css
@import url("//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.2/normalize.min.css");
figure {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
}
img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100vw;
}
figcaption {
  flex: none;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<figure>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/640/480/fashion" />
  <figcaption>Whatever the foobar,<br>she said</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is one way:

### **[FIDDLE #1](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/es8h1qc9/7/)** (Small image)

### **[FIDDLE #2](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/es8h1qc9/6/)** (Large width-to-height ratio)

### **[FIDDLE #3](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/es8h1qc9/5/)** (Large height-to-width ratio)

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.wpr {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  /* align vertical */
  justify-content: center;
  /* align horizontal */
  height: 100vh;
}
figure {
  text-align: center;
}
figcaption {
  width: 350px;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
img {
  max-width: 80vw; /* shrink img to viewport */
  max-height: 80vh; /* shrink img to viewport */
}
```

```html
<div class="wpr">
  <figure>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80" alt="">
    <figcaption>Caption for the awesome picture Caption for the awesome picture Caption for the awesome picture</figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
```

Comment: @ThePragmatick 1) In the images he has set the caption text to some fixed width (as apposed to taking the width of the image) 2) Also the image shows the cation text as being left-aligned

Comment: @Danield, the image should respect the number of lines in the caption. If the caption doesn't fit the screen, [image should shrink until it does.](http://i.imgur.com/hq5KTZt.png)

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like this? - it's only a simple example, but could be what you're looking to achieve.

```css
.container {
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="myImg" src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300" alt="" />

  <div class="caption">I'm a very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long caption</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think I got it working, it does require you to specify if the image is portrait or landscape.

You can see it live her: http://bekreatief.github.io/demo/flexbox_img_with_captions/

```
<div class="screen">
  <div class="img landscape"><img src="http://fc07.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2014/174/1/7/17a514b56717abed29512fddb462de82-d7nmo0f.png" alt="img_wide" /><span class="caption">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas quibusdam voluptas vel facilis sunt quod consectetur assumenda praesentium perferendis nesciunt.</span></div>
</div>
<div class="screen">
  <div class="img portrait"><img src="http://th01.deviantart.net/fs70/PRE/i/2012/016/0/d/ruffles_version_ii_by_mynimi94-d4mj9fv.png" alt="img_high" /><span class="caption">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea amet minus architecto quidem ab quisquam id, corrupti suscipit placeat natus neque cum ex enim eveniet quasi facere, eum asperiores distinctio.</span></div>
</div>
```

Check out the full code here: https://github.com/bekreatief/bekreatief.github.io/tree/master/demo/flexbox_img_with_captions

```
// Sass
.screen{
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  @include flexbox(row, wrap, center, center);

  &:nth-of-type(1){
    top: 0;
  }

  &:nth-of-type(2){
    top: 100vh;
  }

  &:nth-of-type(3){
    top: 200vh;
  }

  .img{
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    @include flexbox(column, nowrap, center, center);

    span{
      text-align: left;
    }
  }
  .landscape{
    img{
      max-height: 100vh;
      max-width: 100%;
    }
  }
  .portrait{
    img{
      height: 100vh;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks pretty nice, but images fail to scale properly in Firefox.

Comment: I created the demo in Firefox. With what screen resolution? I tested all of the common ones.

Comment: 1) [image is wider than the screen, gets cropped horizontally](http://i.imgur.com/K88UktM.jpg);
2) [image gets distorted when shrunk vertically](http://i.imgur.com/IVy8YJf.png).

Comment: you are right, that does not look good. I'll have a look. But I suppose that it will not be possible without javascript. Is that fine or does it have to be CSS-only?